# What happens with a pl/sql procedure on the database server when connection is lost?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

There is a PL/SQL procedure that takes about 15 minutes to execute. From a client program, a connection is created and the following statement is executed:

```
CALL my_proc()
```

Now, what happens on the server side if the connection is lost during execution of `my_proc`? Will the procedure proceed until finished, or will it be aborted?

Comment: what is the client program? any special settings? Usually it should proceed but no results will be shown, You can check the status of procedure in the DB logs (or in Toad session browser)

Comment: The client program is in this particular case a Windows service that uses the OCI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be aborted. When TCP connection is lost a signal is delivered to Oracle session process. The session will either quit instantly OR will rollback the transaction and will quit afterwards.

So if you kill a client program and OS sends FIN packet to DB server when execution is interrupted and transaction is rolled back.